# Router for gigabit connection

Tags: router

Im looking for recommendations for which router to buy for my new gigabit connection at home.

I have:

- a 1000mbit/1000mbit connection
- a small apartment with no thick walls
- maximum three devices connected at the same time (ps4, laptop, stationary computer, phone)

I want:

- wifi performance benchmarked with (very) good results (will mostly be used on 5ghz band and I want to be able to utilize as much of the potential speed as possible)
- good ethernet speed (will be connected to the stationary computer)
- preferably not overly expensive (300$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for the routers with the best 5 GHz Wi-Fi performance I would recommend you this product:

Best choice to $300:

- [ASUS RT-AC3100](https://www.asus.com/us/Networking/RT-AC3100/specifications/) - [$300 on newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833320242)

It's actually one of the best if not the best dual band router on market. It has slightly better results than WRT1900ACS in 5 GHz speeds and additional features like WTFast and MU-MIMO. But it's also $100 more expensive so you have to think if you need sliglitly better performance and additional features for this price.

---

[CNET](http://www.cnet.com/products/asus-rt-ac88u-router/2/) test of this routers Wi-Fi performance (short distance - 15 feet / long distance - 100 feet):

**5 GHz**

- RT-AC88U - **644/345 Mbps**

**2.4 GHz**

- RT-AC88U - **229/102 Mbps**

Comment: Thanks. What speeds (ethernet and wifi, up/down) have they been benchmarked to deliver?

Comment: @mdc I took a results from [Cnet Asus RT-AC88U review](http://www.cnet.com/products/asus-rt-ac88u-router/2/) because it's the same router as AC3100 just with 8 LAN ports. But there are only Wi-Fi benchmarks I don't know exact results for LAN performance. I will update answer with this results.

Comment: If you have a look here: http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/tools/charts/router/view
The AC88U's results isnt very impressive compared to the best. On the other hand the best ones are not recommended on that site so I'm confused :)

Comment: @mdc I think that for all products you can find bad and good reviews and tests. Actually I use little older and cheaper ASUS router/modem and I'm really happy with it (software/performance). I also read some reviews of this products (Asus and Linksys) in my native language and their were really positive. If you are confused and don't want to choose it yet I recommend you to wait for other users opinions and answers maybe it will help you in deciding what to buy.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the routers with the best 5 GHz Wi-Fi performance I would recommend you this product:

Best choice to $200:

- [Linksys WRT1900ACS](http://www.linksys.com/us/p/P-WRT1900ACS/) - [$200 on newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833124605)

This router is really good when we are talking about Wi-Fi speed and stability. It's best choice in AC1900 routers in my opinion and best choice for you.

[CNET](http://www.cnet.com/products/asus-rt-ac88u-router/2/) test of this routers Wi-Fi performance (short distance - 15 feet / long distance - 100 feet): 5 GHz

**5 GHz**

- WRT1900ACS - **536/349 Mbps**

**2.4 GHz**

- WRT1900ACS - **170/59 Mbps**